# How to delete file using drupal_form_submit?

Tags: forms, files, services

I'm using rest services with a custom resource on node update, i want to build the correct variable node structure to delete one of the files on a file image multiple fields.
I removed the file element from the `form_state['values']` but isn't working.
I know i can do it manually but is it possible altering `form_state['values]`  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your form submit function

```
$file ='public://not_imported_longanswer.csv';
$path = $base_url . '/sites/default/files/not_imported_longanswer.csv';
if (file_exists($file)) {
    file_delete($path);
}
```

Comment: thank you but i want to know if its possible only altering removing the field value on the form submitted array

Comment: Example: unset($form_state['values']['field_image'][LANGUAGE_NONE][3]);

Comment: you use unlink function instead of unset